# Probability that doesn't add up to 1

Tags: probability

Let's say that we play 10 rounds of a game. The possible events are:
1. I win
2.You win
3. It may be draw

So we are looking at 3/10 probability of each one ( we assume that all three are equally likely). So they add up to 0.9 as follows:
0.3+0.3+0.3=0.9. The question is where did the 0.1 part of the total probability go... I.e where did the 0.1 miss out? Or did I miss out anywhere or what's happening..

Comment: "So we are looking at $3/10$ probability ... ." Why?

Answer (score 4):

The $0.1$ part is missing because you did not put it there. If all possibilities have the same probability, then the probability of each of them is $\frac13$, not $0.3$.

Comment: Great but doesn't the number of games played matter?

Comment: By the way 1/3 is the same as 0.3...

Comment: *No it isn't!!* $$\frac13=0.\dot{3}=0.33333333333....\neq0.3$$

Comment: Well then 0.3333....+0.333333....+0.33333....=1 ??

Comment: It equals $0.\dot{9}$ which any competent mathematician will tell you is $1$

Comment: @PrateekFeynmanist **How** does the number of games matter? If it were a series of $13$ games, would the probability become $4/13$? Or something else?